# Printing Vec2 x value

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am new on c++, I try to print Vec2 value but it prints 0 always.
My code:

```
Vec2 v[2] = {Vec2(12, 330), Vec2(122, 313) }; 
for (auto value : v ) {
    CCLOG("x: %d", value.x ); 
}
```

How can I fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x, y values are float

CCLOG("x: %f", value.x );

I though it was int